# Is there a single event which gets triggered before a project is started?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I'm writing an extension which needs to set command line arguments on a project before it is started in visual studio.
Currently, I try to handle the different events which lead to a project start.
However, some cases are hard to get right, e.g. pressing F10/F11.

Is there a single event which gets explicitly triggered before a project is started?
Preferably an IVS* interface API.

Note that there are several ways to start a project in visual studio with or without a debugger, thus reacting to Start/StartNoDebug commands are not a feasible solution.